# Python Google Speech to Text timeout "operation was cancelled"

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to use Google Speech to text to transcribe audio from a microphone in realtime.  I also want to set a timeout for how long Google will wait before it times out.  I have tried to use the following code in python

```
client = speech.SpeechClient()
activityTimeout = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig.VoiceActivityTimeout()
activityTimeout.speech_start_timeout = Duration(seconds=60)
config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=SAMPLE_RATE,
    language_code="en-US",
    max_alternatives=1,
    model="command_and_search",
    use_enhanced=True,
)

streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
    config=config, 
    interim_results=False, 
    enable_voice_activity_events=True, 
    voice_activity_timeout=activityTimeout
)
```

However, everytime I make the call to Google with the audio content, all I ever get back is:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Cancelled: 499 The operation was cancelled.
```

And the stack trace goes back to this file:

```
google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 115, in __next__
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here to make a call with a timeout?

If I do not use a timeout, everything works perfectly except for the fact the program sits there waiting for something to send to Google for transcription.  I want the program to timeout after a set time period such as 60 seconds.

Comment: Google Speech to text has some limitations and quota limits. For more information you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content)?

Comment: Have you find the solution to this problem ?